# problems with chdir in PHP script to call a shell script

Tags: php, linux, bash

I am trying to use a PHP script to call a shell script and print the output to the browser.

I have confirmed that all permissions settings are set correctly, both the PHP and the bash script have full control.

If I run the shell script in the current directory (same directory as the PHP file) then it works fine. But if I try to run the shell script from /some/other/directory/shell.script, then it does not work. Why is this so?

I have tried to chdir() to the other directory, but after running a getcwd(), it never changed directories.

I have also tried the exec command by itself and it does not work.

```
<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors',1);

echo "<h1>EDS Count Report</h1><p>";

$output=shell_exec('cd /app/script/catalog/ && ./EDScount_report.sh');
echo $output;
?>
```

contents of SHELL script:

`#!/bin/bash
echo "this is a test!"`

Comment: Are you sure you have no software like CHROOT installed? open_basedir could also limitate the access in your filesystem.

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1); `then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.

Comment: I added that in the header, but it's still not showing any error messages. When I try to run the php file from the command line, I get an error: 
`builder@ae-prod-lxb101:/build2/php/dev> ./phpfile.php4
./phpfile.php4: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./phpfile.php4: line 1: `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors',1);'`

Answer (score 1):

Try this please

```
<?php
$output=shell_exec('sh /path/to/otherdirectory/shellscript.sh');
echo $output;
?>
```

if you are certain that you can access that dicertory , you can use also this:

```
<?php
    $output=shell_exec('cd /path/to/otherdirectory/ && ./shellscript.sh');
    echo $output;
    ?>
```

Comment: That did not make a difference unfortunately.

Comment: why was this down voted? I still can't seem to solve this problem.